# Core data is saving managed objects but data is not persisting between app launches

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Managed object context is supposed to save automatically right? And I think it is doing it because during the time the app is running, the data can be fetched correctly, but between app launches, the data is gone.

Here are my methods to create the context:

```
+ (NSManagedObjectContext *)createMainQueueGameActivityManagedObjectContext
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = nil;

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self createPersistentStoreCoordinatorWithInvestingGameActivityFilename:InvestingGameActivityDatabaseFilename withDataModelFilename:InvestingGameActivityDataModelFilename];

    if (coordinator != nil) {
        managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
        [managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }

    return managedObjectContext;
}

+ (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)createPersistentStoreCoordinatorWithInvestingGameActivityFilename:(NSString *)databaseFilename withDataModelFilename:(NSString *)dataModelFilename
{
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator = nil;
    NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [self createManagedObjectModelWithDataModelFilename:dataModelFilename];

    NSString *databasePathComponent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", databaseFilename, DatabaseFileExtension];

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:databasePathComponent];

    NSError *error = nil;
    persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];
    if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
         */
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

+ (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}

+ (NSManagedObjectModel *)createManagedObjectModelWithDataModelFilename:(NSString *)dataModelFilename
{
    NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = nil;
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:dataModelFilename withExtension:DataModelFileExtension];
    managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];

    return managedObjectModel;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Managed object context is supposed to save automatically right?

**No.**

> And I think it is doing it because during the time the app is running, the data can be fetched correctly, but between app launches, the data is gone.

A managed object context is often compared to a scratch pad. You can read objects into the context from the persistent store, you can add new objects to the context, and you can make changes to objects in the context. As long as the app is running, all those changes will exist in the context. But when the app quits, the context goes away and your changes are lost unless you save its contents back to the persistent store. To do that, you need to call the [`-save:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/save:) method.